# summarising multiple non-exclusive dummy variables in R into one variable

Tags: r, summary

I was sent a dataset with multiple dummy variables and other variables as well. Basically what I´d like to do is create summary table with summary.formula from rms. However, I do not know how to create a single variable from the multiple dummy variables and they are not mutually exclusive. Is this at all possible. Of course I could do it creating a table etc, but then I cannot use summary.formula and I´d like the summary.formula output to include just the individual levels of the dummy variables.

edit:
to clarify: a & b need to be summarized, but they are not mutually exclusive. Since age is recorded for every row I need to summarize a & b into one variable for it to be used in summary.formula. I´ve edited the code below so that 0 and 1 are changed into NA or a,b respectively.

I´d like the summary.formula output to be something like this:

```
h<-data.frame(a=sample(c("A",NA),100,replace=T),b=sample(c("B",NA),100,replace=T),age=rnorm(100,50,25),epo=sample(c("Y","N"),100,T))





library(rms)

summary.formula(epo~age####+summary variable of a & b######,method="reverse",data=h)



#-----------------
 Descriptive Statistics by epo

+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|         |N                         |Y                         |
|         |(N=56)                    |(N=44)                    |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|age      |31.53434/48.90788/67.69096|28.63689/43.93502/57.81834|
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|sab : A  |         25% (14)         |         16% ( 7)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|   B     |         27% (15)         |         32% (14)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to combine binary variables into a single variable, but how you do it depends on their meaning and what you desire the single variable to indicate. If you provide some more details about what you want the single variable to mean, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Using paste() seems to work acceptably.

```
h$sab <- paste(h$a, h$b, sep="_")
summary.formula(epo~age+sab,method="reverse",data=h)
#-----------------
 Descriptive Statistics by epo

+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|         |N                         |Y                         |
|         |(N=56)                    |(N=44)                    |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|age      |31.53434/48.90788/67.69096|28.63689/43.93502/57.81834|
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|sab : 0_0|         25% (14)         |         16% ( 7)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|    0_1  |         27% (15)         |         32% (14)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|    1_0  |         25% (14)         |         34% (15)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|    1_1  |         23% (13)         |         18% ( 8)         |
+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Another option might be interaction():

```
summary.formula(epo~age+interaction(a,b),method="reverse",data=h)
```

If instead you want a logical 'OR" applied to the combination of variables, then use:

```
h$a_or_b <- with(h, a|b)
summary.formula(epo ~ age+ h$a_or_b,method="reverse",data=h)
```

Comment: Problem being that the sab variable should just contain a or b- not a_and_b, a_and_a or b_and_b.. I want to summarize just by a or b-and they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm sure Dwin can update this answer to address this easily, but one method would be to create a new variable h$c <- (h$a + h$b) == 1.

Comment: @Misha: You need to clarify what you want. Your use of the logical terms "or" and "and" appears confused. In no way am I creating any variable levels with "a_and_a" or "b_and_b". The four levels created are  a=0&b=0, a=0%b=1, a=1&b=0, and a=1&b=1. Do you just want max(a,b)?