# Summarizing multiple dummies in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

Say I've asked 10 people which fruits they like. More than one answer is possible. The results are entered into R like so:

```
set.seed(234078)
df <- data.frame(q1.banana = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 q1.apple  = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 q1.melon  = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

So that

```
> df
   q1.banana q1.apple q1.melon
1          0        0        1
2          0        1        1
3          1        1        0
4          1        0        0
5          0        1        1
6          0        0        0
7          1        0        0
8          0        0        0
9          0        1        1
10         0        0        1
```

**How can I summarize the information in a table like the following?**

```
q1.*    Freq
banana     3
apple      4
melon      5
```

After searching, I've found [a couple of ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193113/1169233) such as using `interaction(q1.banana, q1.apple, q1.melon)`, but that gives a different kind of output. Moreover, I would really appreciate if your answer involves a wild card, because my real case is expected to have few dozen dummies and I don't want to write them all.

Comment: Perhaps, manipulating `colSums(df)` a bit, could be get you there?

Comment: There is also the `multi.table` function from the "questionr" package if your data are not all ones and zeroes,  but for dummy data like this `colSums` makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be one option.

```
set.seed(234078)
df <- data.frame(q1.banana = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 q1.apple  = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 q1.melon  = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

library(reshape2)
# Melt the data 
df1 <- melt(df)

df1$value <- as.numeric(df1$value)

library(plyr)

# Now use ddply to sum the values
ddply(df1,.(variable),summarize,Freq=sum(value))
   variable Freq
1 q1.banana    3
2  q1.apple    4
3  q1.melon    5
```

Another option

```
> colSums(df)
q1.banana  q1.apple  q1.melon 
        3         4         5
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `colSums()`. Why would anyone choose option 1, BTW? Thanks!

Comment: After melting, why do you do `as.numeric`? Also, you don't need "plyr" for this: `dcast(df1, variable ~ "Freq", fun.aggregate=sum)` works too. With the data in the long form, you could also just do `table(df1)` and get frequencies of both ones and zeroes. @WaldirLeoncio, `colSums` makes the most sense here, but having your data in a long form can make way for different types of aggregation functions.